# OpenCL with amdgpu: Pseudo instruction errors

Tags: gpu, opencl, gpgpu, amd-gpu

I'm currently writing some OpenCL code (in Linux). For code that works fine on a Intel CPU the following error arrises when I try to use the AMD GPU:

```
AMDGPUMCInstLower::lower - Pseudo instruction doesn't have a target-specific version: 317
```

This code produces the error for example (but only if lines 33 and 35 are there, if they are commented out the error goes away:
https://paste.pound-python.org/show/k4unI4Bf1TVDEiAZj7be/

The error occurs also in other codes in (like it seams) unrelated positions but sometimes with other numbers at the end.

I could not find anything about this type of error. Updating LLVM and Mesa to a newer version did also not change anything.

My configuration:

- GPU: Polaris 11 (Radeon RX 460)
- Driver: amdgpu
- Kernel: 4.7.5 (Gentoo)
- Mesa: 12.0.3
- LLVM: 3.8.1-rc2
- gcc/gfortran: 6.2.0

What exactly does this error mean and how can I get rid of it? It causes the build to fail and makes OpenCL essentially unusable at the moment.

Comment: What is the `clinfo` output?